# Good CRM commercial or open source

Tags: php, mysql, linux, crm, redhat

Can someone please recommend a good CRM system?  If this question should not be asked here, please let me know where to ask it as I thought this was the best place.

Comment: belongs on superuser, voting to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about vtiger http://www.vtiger.com/

Answer (score 2):

After checking out a few cloud-based services, we chose [CapsuleCRM](http://capsulecrm.com) because of its easy integration with our cloud-based accounting system (Xero). We did have a look at Zoho too.

And you're right, this is not the place to ask this question - perhaps try superuser, but I'm not sure. Also not sure why you've used those other tags for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is new and pretty simple - [Onekloud CRM](http://www.onekloud.com).